# org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne:

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I'm trying to set up a OneToOne relationship using Hibernate. I've tried doing what the other questions suggest, but I'm still getting issues.

I have a Company class that has its own set of Warehouse Rules. Each entity has a BusinessUnitNumber as the Id of the table.

```
@Entity(name="COBUSMST")
public class Company implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2573441991172174342L;
    private Integer businessUnit;
    private String longName;
    private String shortName;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipCode;
    private String returnAddress1;
    private String returnAddress2;
    private String returnCity;
    private String returnState;
    private String returnZipCode;
    private int phoneNumber;
    private int areaCode;
    private boolean replacementCharge;
    private BigDecimal replacementChargeAmount;
    private String customerServiceKeycode;
    private BigDecimal restockPercent;
    private Integer enterpriseId;
    private String country;
    private String returnCountry;
    private int phoneExtension;
    private String phoneType;
    private String giftCardItemNumber;
    private boolean implementationStatus;
    private int defaultWebsiteId;
    private BigDecimal callTagFee;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="BUSUNTNBR")
    private WarehouseRules warehouseRules;

    /**
     * @return the businessUnit
     */
    @Id
    @Column(name="BUSUNTNBR")
    public Integer getBusinessUnit() {
        return businessUnit;
    }
    /**
     * @param businessUnit the businessUnit to set
     */
    public void setBusinessUnit(Integer businessUnit) {
        this.businessUnit = businessUnit;
    }
    /**
     * @return the longName
     */
    @Column(name="LNGNAM")
    public String getLongName() {
        return longName;
    }
    /**
     * @param longName the longName to set
     */
    public void setLongName(String longName) {
        this.longName = longName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the shortName
     */
    @Column(name="SRTNAM")
    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }
    /**
     * @param shortName the shortName to set
     */
    public void setShortName(String shortName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the address1
     */
    @Column(name="ADR1")
    public String getAddress1() {
        return address1;
    }
    /**
     * @param address1 the address1 to set
     */
    public void setAddress1(String address1) {
        this.address1 = address1;
    }
    /**
     * @return the address2
     */
    @Column(name="ADR2")
    public String getAddress2() {
        return address2;
    }
    /**
     * @param address2 the address2 to set
     */
    public void setAddress2(String address2) {
        this.address2 = address2;
    }
    /**
     * @return the city
     */
    @Column(name="CTY")
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    /**
     * @param city the city to set
     */
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    /**
     * @return the state
     */
    @Column(name="STA")
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    /**
     * @param state the state to set
     */
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    /**
     * @return the zipCode
     */
    @Column(name="PSTCOD")
    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }
    /**
     * @param zipCode the zipCode to set
     */
    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }
    /**
     * @return the returnAddress1
     */
    @Column(name="RTNADR1")
    public String getReturnAddress1() {
        return returnAddress1;
    }
    /**
     * @param returnAddress1 the returnAddress1 to set
     */
    public void setReturnAddress1(String returnAddress1) {
        this.returnAddress1 = returnAddress1;
    }
    /**
     * @return the returnAddress2
     */
    @Column(name="RTNADR2")
    public String getReturnAddress2() {
        return returnAddress2;
    }
    /**
     * @param returnAddress2 the returnAddress2 to set
     */
    public void setReturnAddress2(String returnAddress2) {
        this.returnAddress2 = returnAddress2;
    }
    /**
     * @return the returnCity
     */
    @Column(name="RTNCTY")
    public String getReturnCity() {
        return returnCity;
    }
    /**
     * @param returnCity the returnCity to set
     */
    public void setReturnCity(String returnCity) {
        this.returnCity = returnCity;
    }
    /**
     * @return the returnState
     */
    @Column(name="RTNSTA")
    public String getReturnState() {
        return returnState;
    }
    /**
     * @param returnState the returnState to set
     */
    public void setReturnState(String returnState) {
        this.returnState = returnState;
    }
    /**
     * @return the returnZipCode
     */
    @Column(name="RTNPSTCOD")
    public String getReturnZipCode() {
        return returnZipCode;
    }
    /**
     * @param returnZipCode the returnZipCode to set
     */
    public void setReturnZipCode(String returnZipCode) {
        this.returnZipCode = returnZipCode;
    }
    /**
     * @return the phoneNumber
     */
    @Column(name="PHNNUM")
    public int getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @param phoneNumber the phoneNumber to set
     */
    public void setPhoneNumber(int phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @return the areaCode
     */
    @Column(name="ARACOD")
    public int getAreaCode() {
        return areaCode;
    }
    /**
     * @param areaCode the areaCode to set
     */
    public void setAreaCode(int areaCode) {
        this.areaCode = areaCode;
    }
    /**
     * @return the replacementCharge
     */
    @Column(name="RPLCHRFLG")
    @Type(type="yes_no")
    public boolean isReplacementCharge() {
        return replacementCharge;
    }
    /**
     * @param replacementCharge the replacementCharge to set
     */
    public void setReplacementCharge(boolean replacementCharge) {
        this.replacementCharge = replacementCharge;
    }
    /**
     * @return the replacementChargeAmount
     */
    @Column(name="RPLCHRAMT")
    public BigDecimal getReplacementChargeAmount() {
        return replacementChargeAmount;
    }
    /**
     * @param replacementChargeAmount the replacementChargeAmount to set
     */
    public void setReplacementChargeAmount(BigDecimal replacementChargeAmount) {
        this.replacementChargeAmount = replacementChargeAmount;
    }
    /**
     * @return the customerServiceKeycode
     */
    @Column(name="CUSSVCKEY")
    public String getCustomerServiceKeycode() {
        return customerServiceKeycode;
    }
    /**
     * @param customerServiceKeycode the customerServiceKeycode to set
     */
    public void setCustomerServiceKeycode(String customerServiceKeycode) {
        this.customerServiceKeycode = customerServiceKeycode;
    }
    /**
     * @return the restockPercent
     */
    @Column(name="RSKPCT")
    public BigDecimal getRestockPercent() {
        return restockPercent;
    }
    /**
     * @param restockPercent the restockPercent to set
     */
    public void setRestockPercent(BigDecimal restockPercent) {
        this.restockPercent = restockPercent;
    }
    /**
     * @return the enterpriseId
     */
    @Column(name="ETRID")
    public Integer getEnterpriseId() {
        return enterpriseId;
    }
    /**
     * @param enterpriseId the enterpriseId to set
     */
    public void setEnterpriseId(Integer enterpriseId) {
        this.enterpriseId = enterpriseId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the country
     */
    @Column(name="CRY")
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    /**
     * @param country the country to set
     */
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    /**
     * @return the returnCountry
     */
    @Column(name="RTNCRY")
    public String getReturnCountry() {
        return returnCountry;
    }
    /**
     * @param returnCountry the returnCountry to set
     */
    public void setReturnCountry(String returnCountry) {
        this.returnCountry = returnCountry;
    }
    /**
     * @return the phoneExtension
     */
    @Column(name="PHNEXT")
    public int getPhoneExtension() {
        return phoneExtension;
    }
    /**
     * @param phoneExtension the phoneExtension to set
     */
    public void setPhoneExtension(int phoneExtension) {
        this.phoneExtension = phoneExtension;
    }
    /**
     * @return the phoneType
     */
    @Column(name="PHNTYPCLF")
    public String getPhoneType() {
        return phoneType;
    }
    /**
     * @param phoneType the phoneType to set
     */
    public void setPhoneType(String phoneType) {
        this.phoneType = phoneType;
    }
    /**
     * @return the giftCardItemNumber
     */
    @Column(name="GFTCTFITM")
    public String getGiftCardItemNumber() {
        return giftCardItemNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @param giftCardItemNumber the giftCardItemNumber to set
     */
    public void setGiftCardItemNumber(String giftCardItemNumber) {
        this.giftCardItemNumber = giftCardItemNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @return the implementationStatus
     */
    @Column(name="IMPSTSFLG")
    @Type(type="yes_no")
    public boolean isImplementationStatus() {
        return implementationStatus;
    }
    /**
     * @param implementationStatus the implementationStatus to set
     */
    public void setImplementationStatus(boolean implementationStatus) {
        this.implementationStatus = implementationStatus;
    }
    /**
     * @return the defaultWebsiteId
     */
    @Column(name="DFTWEBID")
    public int getDefaultWebsiteId() {
        return defaultWebsiteId;
    }
    /**
     * @param defaultWebsiteId the defaultWebsiteId to set
     */
    public void setDefaultWebsiteId(int defaultWebsiteId) {
        this.defaultWebsiteId = defaultWebsiteId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the callTagFee
     */
    @Column(name="CTGFEEAMT")
    public BigDecimal getCallTagFee() {
        return callTagFee;
    }
    /**
     * @param callTagFee the callTagFee to set
     */
    public void setCallTagFee(BigDecimal callTagFee) {
        this.callTagFee = callTagFee;
    }
    /**
     * @return the warehouseRules
     */
    public WarehouseRules getWarehouseRules() {
        return warehouseRules;
    }
    /**
     * @param warehouseRules the warehouseRules to set
     */
    public void setWarehouseRules(WarehouseRules warehouseRules) {
        this.warehouseRules = warehouseRules;   
}
```

My WarehouseRules class is as follows.

```
@Entity(name = "COBRLWHS")
public class WarehouseRules implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1967521668154976367L;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="warehouseRules")
    private Company company;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "BUSUNTNBR")
    private Integer businessUnit;

    @Column(name="ORDPTYCLF")
    private String orderPriority;

    @Column(name="WHSPPRCLF")
    private String warehousePaperwork;

    @Column(name="ENTCUTTIM")
    private Time entryCutoffTime;

    @Column(name = "RRLADLDAY")
    private Integer ruralDays;

    @Column(name = "SRRADLDAY")
    private Integer superRuralDays;

    @Column(name = "BOADLDAY")
    private Integer backorderDays;

    @Column(name = "DFTFRTTBL")
    private String freightTable;

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        setBusinessUnit(id);
    }

    /**
     * @return the businessUnit
     */
    public Integer getBusinessUnit() {
        return businessUnit;
    }

    /**
     * @param businessUnit the businessUnit to set
     */
    public void setBusinessUnit(Integer businessUnit) {
        this.businessUnit = businessUnit;
    }

    /**
     * @return the ruralDays
     */
    public Integer getRuralDays() {
        return ruralDays;
    }

    /**
     * @param ruralDays the ruralDays to set
     */
    public void setRuralDays(Integer ruralDays) {
        this.ruralDays = ruralDays;
    }

    /**
     * @return the superRuralDays
     */
    public Integer getSuperRuralDays() {
        return superRuralDays;
    }

    /**
     * @param superRuralDays the superRuralDays to set
     */
    public void setSuperRuralDays(Integer superRuralDays) {
        this.superRuralDays = superRuralDays;
    }

    /**
     * @return the backorderDays
     */
    public Integer getBackorderDays() {
        return backorderDays;
    }

    /**
     * @param backorderDays the backorderDays to set
     */
    public void setBackorderDays(Integer backorderDays) {
        this.backorderDays = backorderDays;
    }

    /**
     * @return the freightTable
     */
    public String getFreightTable() {
        return freightTable;
    }

    /**
     * @param freightTable the freightTable to set
     */
    public void setFreightTable(String freightTable) {
        this.freightTable = freightTable;
    }   

    /**
     * @return the orderPriority
     */
    public String getOrderPriority() {
        return orderPriority;
    }

    /**
     * @param orderPriority the orderPriority to set
     */
    public void setOrderPriority(String orderPriority) {
        this.orderPriority = orderPriority;
    }

    /**
     * @return the warehousePaperwork
     */
    public String getWarehousePaperwork() {
        return warehousePaperwork;
    }

    /**
     * @param warehousePaperwork the warehousePaperwork to set
     */
    public void setWarehousePaperwork(String warehousePaperwork) {
        this.warehousePaperwork = warehousePaperwork;
    }

    /**
     * @return the entryCutoffTime
     */
    public Time getEntryCutoffTime() {
        return entryCutoffTime;
    }

    /**
     * @param entryCutoffTime the entryCutoffTime to set
     */
    public void setEntryCutoffTime(Time entryCutoffTime) {
        this.entryCutoffTime = entryCutoffTime;
    }



    /**
     * @return the company
     */
    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    /**
     * @param company the company to set
     */
    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = prime * result
                + ((businessUnit == null) ? 0 : businessUnit.hashCode());
        return result;
    }


    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!super.equals(obj))
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        WarehouseRules other = (WarehouseRules) obj;
        if (businessUnit == null) {
            if (other.businessUnit != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!businessUnit.equals(other.businessUnit))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I try to run my code, I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne: com.oriental.comet.db2.company.entity.Company.warehouseRules in mappedBy of com.oriental.comet.db2.company.entity.WarehouseRules.company:org.hibernate.AnnotationException:Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne: com.oriental.comet.db2.company.entity.Company.warehouseRules in mappedBy of com.oriental.comet.db2.company.entity.WarehouseRules.company
    at org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1697)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1426)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
```

The only thing I can think of is the fact that both tables have the same column name for their ID? I can't change that though, so I don't know if there is a workaround (if that's truly the case) or if I'm missing something.

Comment: can you share your session code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class `Company` you have annotated a FIELD (`warehouseRules`) yet all others in that class use PROPERTY. You should use **either** PROPERTY **or** FIELD but not a mix. Perhaps if you be consistent your JPA provider will see sense?

Clearly the message could be clearer, stressing that you haven't annotated the PROPERTY (getter). Other JPA providers don't necessarily insist on the OneToOne/OneToMany annotations since it is clear from the property/field type that it is a relation.

Comment: Awesome! That worked. I moved the annotation to the getter to match all the others in the Company class and everything is good.

Answer (score 0):

I provide you with a simple example:
Person and Address have a one-to-one relationship.
To achieve this I use the **shared primary key association**:
Person class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "person_pk", nullable = false)
private Long personPk;

@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Address address;
```

Address class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "myForeignGenerator")
@GenericGenerator(name = "myForeignGenerator", 
                    strategy = "foreign", 
                    parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "person"))
@Column(name = "address_pk")
private Long addressPk;

@OneToOne(targetEntity = Person.class)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Person person;
```

To persist the transient object:

```
Person person = new Person();
Address address = new Address();
person.setAddress(address);
address.setPerson(person);

persist(person);
```

This is how the database schema looks like:
person table

```
person_pk <<PK>>
```

address table

```
address_pk <<PK>><<FK>>
```

Read it as follows: when an **Address** is saved, the primary key value is taken from the **person** property. The **person** property is a reference to a **Person** object; hence the primary key value that is inserted is the same as the primary key value of that instance.